# How To Return Query For Name of Stock Ticker From Corporation Name In R

Tags: r, quantitative-finance

Doing a project where I need to scrape https://www.sec.gov/divisions/enforce/friactions/friactions2017.shtml.

Basically I have compiled a list of the SEC AAER releases, which ends up being a list of private and public companies. What I need to do is to return the ticker from the corporation. Any idea of R packages that would be useful for this.

As an example, I would want to have "PCRFY" return for Panasonic Corporation. However, this might be an issue: there are two listings for KPMG, one being just "KPMG" and the other being "KPMG Inc." How can I make sure that both queries return a result?

An example of an equation would be:

```
    returnTicker(("Panasonic Corporation","Apple Corporation"))
```

Which would return:

```
    ("PCRFY","APPL")
```

Comment: So you have a list of names that you want to search for using the **Search Accounting and Auditing Releases** search bar on the page?

Comment: Not going to use the search, going to be scraping every single Accounting and Auditing Release. Basically have not been to find an efficient way to convert a list of company Names such as ("Panasonic Corporation","Apple Corporation") into ("PCRFY","AAPL")

Comment: So I guess you would want to fuzzy match the names, and return all the stock symbols which are close matches? For example, *AAPL* is the ticker for [*Apple Inc.*](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/), not *Apple Corporation*. Or do you have the "official" company names?

Comment: Yup, that's pretty spot on.  I don't have always have the exact company names from the SEC cases, so would definitely need a fuzzy match. Know any packages I could use? I may just be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this comes *close* to what you need. It doesn't use fuzzy matching, but it should have comparable results.

It is partially adapted from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383585/turn-list-of-company-names-into-tickers).

```
# The TTR package includes stock symbols and names for NASDAQ, NYSE, and AMEX
library(TTR)

master <- TTR::stockSymbols()[,c('Name', 'Symbol')]

# We are going to clean up the company names by removing some unimportant words.
# Replace the words ' Incorporated', ' Corporated', and ' Corporation' with '' (no text), and put results in master$clean.
master <- cbind(master, clean = gsub(' Incorporated| Corporated| Corporation', '', master$Name))

# Some further cleaning of the master$clean column (the straight line | seperates the strings we are removing)...
master$clean <- gsub(', Inc|, Inc.| Inc| Inc.| Corp|, Corp| Corp.|, Corp.| Ltd.| Ltd', '', master$clean)

# Clean some special characters. For explanations, check out http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/gsub.php
master$clean <- gsub('\\(The\\)|[.]|\'|,', '', master$clean)

# You should also do the 3 cleaning cleaning steps above on your company names as well.
# Lastly, scroll through your data; you may find some more character strings to remove.

# Create a data frame which would contain your company names....
yourCompanyNames <- data.frame(name = c('apple', 'microsoft', 'allstate', 'ramp capital'), stringsAsFactors = F)

# This is the important part. Symbols are added to the data frame of yourCompanyNames....
yourCompanyNames$sym <- sapply(X = yourCompanyNames$name, FUN = function(YOUR.NAME) {
  master[grep(pattern = YOUR.NAME, x = master$clean, ignore.case = T), 'Symbol'] })

#  ------------ END ---------------

# I dunno how much R experience you have, but here is a quick explanation of what is happening, chunk-by-chunk...

# companyNames$sym <-
  # Create a new column in your dataframe for the symbols we will be finding

# sapply(X = yourCompanyNames$name, FUN = function(YOUR.NAME) {
  # sapply() applies a function (found on the next line) to your data (X).

# master[grep(
  # grep() searches for a string in a vector of strings, and will return the indices where it is found. For example...
  # grep('hel', c('hello', 'world', 'help')) returns 1 and 3

# pattern = YOUR.NAME, x = master$clean, ignore.case = T),
  # The pattern which grep() is looking for is YOUR.NAME, which is an individual company name from yourCompanyNames.
  # (Remember, we are moving through yourCompanyNames one-by-one)
  # grep() looks for YOUR.NAME in each of the strings in master$clean, and ignores capitalization of the strings.

# 'Symbol'] })
  # We can simplify the second line to master[grep(), 'Symbol']
  # Since grep() is returning indicies where YOUR.NAME is found in master$clean,
  # the second line gives us the symbols for the companies located at those indicies (rows).
  # Finally, sapply() returns the list of symbols we found, and the list is added to yourCompanyName$sym


# Using the 4 example companies from above, we get....

#           name                                                         sym
# 1        apple                                        AAPL, APLE, DPS, MLP
# 2    microsoft                                                        MSFT
# 3     allstate ALL, ALL-PA, ALL-PB, ALL-PC, ALL-PD, ALL-PE, ALL-PF, ALL-PG
# 4 ramp capital                                                            

# The word 'apple' appeared in multiple names, and 'allstate' has multiple tickers.
# You may need to clean some of them up using fix(yourCompanyNames)
```

Hope this helps, or at least puts you on the right path.

Comment: If you are having too many symbols returned for each name, you could force `grep()` to use exact matching by replacing `pattern = YOUR.NAME` with `pattern = paste0('^',YOUR.NAME, '$')`. [Explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813667/how-to-use-grep-to-find-exact-match)

Comment: Have you ever encountered this problem?
        master <- TTR::stockSymbols()[,c('Name', 'Symbol')]
        #Fetching AMEX symbols...
        #Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
        #In addition: Warning message:
        #In file(file, "rt") : InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The operation timed out'